# laravel api put and patch method not accepting request from postman form-data

Tags: laravel, api, patch, put, form-data

I'm creating an update api by using apiresource in laravel 8. im seing request from the postman using put and patch method but it returning empty array. is there any method by using that i can create update api using form-data because i have images in my api byt x-www-form-urlencoded does not give option for to add file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M40Gl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Header on Postman, make sure:

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Comment: already use this but still same issue

Comment: Can you provide more information? Controller, Routes ...

Comment: sure im using apiresource and the controller code is a bit long due to that it will not be posted here